why is cmd taking like 20 seconds to open up in windows 11?
When I run cmd.exe, it takes ~20s to load, but when run as Administrator, it works immediately.
I've tried:

closing background apps, with memory and CPU usage being normal
looking online, but all the answers are for Windows 7 and Vista
using cmd.exe /D, which opened fast at first, but I didn't find the autostart register and using /D now doesn't make it any faster


Do you have a registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor with an item named AutoRun?

@harrymc no i don't

Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

@John it opens perfectly fine in another user

i would love to repair the old one

@harrymc safe mode does make it open normally

yes it does work

@John could you help me repair my profile?

Run Process Monitor and launch it.  It might help understand what's going on, i.e. where the time is lost.  Where does the time jump between events for the process?

@HelpingHand thank you so much for the answer. it seems the duration of everything is very short but for some reason after conhost.exe closes there is just a gap for like 20 seconds and then everything continues normally

just repairing and resetting the terminal fixed it
it can be done like so:
go to setting
go to apps
go to installed apps
scroll down till you find terminal
click 3 dots
advanced options
click on repair and reset

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for it.
To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
Autoruns for Windows.
This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu Options > Hide Microsoft Entries,
Hide Empty Locations and Hide Windows Entries
I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

i tried to disable every single non microsoft that i could and it still didn't work.

I wonder if this means that it's a Microsoft product that does it.
